# ASP.NET Login system

Tags: asp.net

I have created a login system to my website. This login system is supposed to protect one page only (Meaning that there is one page that requires users to login to see it). 
My problem is:
Since I created this login system, all my other 8 pages now require validation. This is not my intention, and I have been searching like crazy for a solution, but no luck.
My web.config file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=5.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="30" />  <!--name =".ASPXFORMSAUTH"-->
  </authentication>

  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

The only page that requires log in is called Default.aspx
The rest of my pages should be public to all users. How can I achieve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using location element within web.config file.

```
<location path="Default.aspx"> 
  <system.web> 
      <authorization> 
            <deny users="?" />
      </authorization> 
   </system.web> 
</location>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "location" in your web.config and specify the directory you want to be protected. Here's a nice example:

http://www.codefixer.com/asp-net/tutorials/protecting-folders-with-forms-authentication.asp